# Maven dependency plugin ignores destination

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I'm using the maven-dependency-plugin from the command line to download a single file, but it always ends up in my local repository when, for my particular use case, I want it to be downloaded to the current directory.

I'm using version 2.4 of the plugin, which should support -Ddestination as an alternate download site; however, I can't get it to work.  Running maven in debug mode seems to indicate that the destination parameter is being ignored...

I'm running the following:

```
M:\>mvn -e -X org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:get \
-Ddestination=M:\test \
-DremoteRepositories=http://nexus-repo:8080/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots \
-Dartifact=com.company.Common:CommonLibs:1.12.0-SNAPSHOT:tar \
-Dtransitive=false
```

... but getting this...

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:get' -->
[DEBUG]   (f) artifact = com.company.Common:CommonLibs:1.12.0-SNAPSHOT:tar
[DEBUG]   (f) localRepository = Repository[local|file://C:\Subversion\LocalMavenRepo]
[DEBUG]   (f) packaging = jar
[DEBUG]   (f) pomRemoteRepositories = [Repository[central|http://repo1.maven.org/maven2]]
[DEBUG]   (f) remoteRepositories = http://nexus-repo:8080/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots
[DEBUG]   (f) repositoryId = temp
[DEBUG]   (f) transitive = false
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] [dependency:get {execution: default-cli}]
[DEBUG] Skipping disabled repository central
[INFO] snapshot com.company.Common:CommonLibs:1.12.0-SNAPSHOT: checking for updates from temp
[DEBUG] Using Wagon implementation lightweight from default mapping for protocol http
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look in the documentation [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html#destination). It says:

> Expression: ${dest}

It means you have to provide the parameter named `dest`. Try to use `-Ddest=M:\test.tar`. Also, it should be file name for the downloaded artefact, not a directory.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out.  I was previously working on the assumption that the expected expression would always be the same as the parameter name.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

In version 3.0.0 this proporty is removed. In version 2.10 destination/dest parameter is deprecated: it will disappear in future version.
Documentation for this is not consistent. In "usage" there is example with property "dest" but in [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html) there is no word about it.